# Hibernate - No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, jpa

I know there has been already a lot of questions concerning this topic, but I've tried everything so far and read everything I could find about it and it still hasn't solved my issue.

I develop a Java Application in Eclipse with Hibernate 5.2.1. Final and SQLite JDBC (Xerial 3.8.11.2) and Maven. Whenever I try to run the project from Eclipse I get this nasty exception:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$156(LauncherImpl.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named database
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at pl.nombritech.Produktor.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:18)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

Of course I checked if my META-INF directory is at a right place (src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml) and if it is included in the classpath. Persistence unit name also corresponds with the name given in Main class:

```
public static final EntityManagerFactory ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
    "database");
```

I don't have a clue why it happens. Whenever I try to launch it from the .jar I get another exception:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
        at pl.nombritech.Produktor.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:18)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$156(LauncherImpl.java:352)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:383)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        ... 5 more
```

At the end I attach my POM.xml and persistence.xml:

POM.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.nombritech</groupId>
    <artifactId>Produktor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Produktor</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- LIBRARIES IN LIB DIRECTORY -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <!-- <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix> -->
                            <mainClass>pl.nombritech.Produktor.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

persistence.xml:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="database" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:bazadb.db" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="pl.nombritech.Produktor.util.SQLiteDialect" />
            <!-- create-drop tworzy i kasuje, create tworzy tylko -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I would appreciate all the help. Please do not write it is a duplicate, because I searched for solution in those topics and none of them were helpful for me. Thank you very much for any help.

PS. I tried this configuration with the previous major version of Hibernate (4.3.11.Final - I guess I only used another provider: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence which is now deprecated and not existent in Hibernate-Core 5) and it worked as a charm, so I really don't know what happened in the version 5, that it acts so differently.

EDIT:

My project structure in Eclipse is:

[Project structure in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfzID.jpg)

EDIT3:

Upload of my project (my own hosting):

[Download my project (Eclipse Project)](http://www.bloodlex.webd.pl/Produktor.zip)

Comment: The file should be named `persistence.xml`, not `persistance.xml`.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake while posting, of course it's "persistence.xml", and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Your Eclipse project seems messed up: `ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence`. Try reimporting the maven project. And why do you have both hibernate-jpa-2.1-api and javax.persistence in your pom?

Comment: I thought I should add that just to be on the safe side in case of javax.persistence.Persistence not being included, as I said I've tried everything to make it run :) I'll try to reimport that in a moment and see what happens

Comment: @JBNizet nothing's changed :( even if I left only hibernate-jpa-2.1... I don't know what to do :( I run out of ideas... and why does it say that there is no persitence provider when I run it from Eclipse? It's just doesn't make sense...

Comment: What happens when you move Eclipse out of the equation, and just use Maven to run the app? Or even the command line? Or when you import your project into IntelliJ instead of Eclipse? What is listed in your Eclipse project structure under "Maven dependencies"?

Comment: @JBNizet I've just added a screenshot illustrating the content of Maven Dependencies to the post above :) If I try to run it with just Maven using `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="pl.nombritech.Produktor.Main"` I get the same exception as the one when I run it from Eclipse, I can try it with IntelliJ in a second

Comment: When you say "the same exception", do you mean the first one, or the second one?

Comment: @JBNizet I mean the one with `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named database` - `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`

Comment: Is your project under github?

Comment: @JBNizet it's local only on my computer

Comment: @JBNizet I've just tried it on IntelliJ Idea and it's still the same exception: `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named database`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you mix eclipseLink and hibernate?
use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and remove the eclipseLink dependency

your copy-dependencies goal should have

```
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
```

finally, when building jar, use this snippet in your maven-jar-plugin. jars should be outside your main jar, not inside it

```
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>pl.nombritech.Produktor.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
```

Comment: I left only that (hibernate-entitymanager) and I'm still getting `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named database`... I really don't know what to do :(

Comment: @Bloodlex are you sure your persistence.xml is copied to target folder?

Comment: the path to the persistence.xml in "target" folder is: `target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml`

Comment: now that's weird... can you upload your project somewhere?

Comment: I uploaded my project on my hosting, you can find the link at the end of the main post :) I hope it helps, because I reached a dead-end :(

Comment: i dont have any problems. i cleaned-packaged the project, window appears and i made a sample select.all (i populated the database, remove d the create property so as not to reset the db, and a list was returned). please maven clean package your project and try again

Comment: have you run it from Eclipse? I'm still getting those errors, I have no idea where do they come from, maybe my JDK is corrupted or something like that? but everything worked fine until now...

Comment: do you have any more ideas what I could do? :(

Comment: Clean your local repo and leg maven redownload all packages jusgin case. I cannot think of sth else. Its a simple project so all are obvious and notcomplicated

Comment: YES! IT WORKS :) Thank you very much! I removed all the local repo and now it works like a charm :) I'd like to thank all of you for help, it was very very strange in such an easy project, I really appreciate that :)

Comment: but now I noticed that when I try to run .jar file I'm getting `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence` as before :( now it works only in Eclipse

Comment: Please accept my answer and upvote it. This is the reward for the help. Thank you

Comment: I ll check later outside eclipse execution and let you know

Comment: I moved the libriaries out of the `lib` folder and now it works :) I've already upvoted it, but I don't have enough reputation for it to be visible :( Thanks once again ^^